# Setting a custom share icon on Actionbar ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, shareactionprovider

I'm trying to set the icon ShareActionProvider, need a solid white one instead of the semi transparent white one.

However setting in share_menu.xml and code doesn't work. Just wondering whether anyone has got workaround for this before extending the ShareActionProvider. (I'm using actionbarsherlock)

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
    MenuItem actionItem = menu.findItem(R.id.share_action_provider);

    ShareActionProvider actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();
     actionProvider.setShareIntent(mShareIntent);

    // re-setting the icon as it's not being picked up from the menu xml file
    actionItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_share);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}
```

share_menu.xml

```
 <item android:id="@+id/share_action_provider"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/share_with"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

Update: 
Also tried setting it in the style, but no joy

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionModeStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionMode">
      <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_share</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When I am looking to customize the action bar, usually the first place I look is the ActionBarSherlock themes and styles.

I found that the Sherlock theme uses the "actionModeShareDrawable" as found in [theme.xml](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/res/values/abs__themes.xml#L43) file.

Try changing your theme to include the "actionModeShareDrawable" item directly.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_share</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This will work only because the internal version is used on all platforms. The built-in `ShareActionProvider` uses a non-public resource to specify the drawable so this solution is very ActionBarSherlock-specific.

Comment: Adding actionModeShareDrawable to the main theme, seems to work on both gingerbread and ics.

Comment: Didn't make a difference for me on JB or GB.

Comment: I am using ActionBarSherlock 4.4.0 and i'm not getting this piece of code working... @JakeWharton do you have a solution for this? I need to customize this icon.

Answer (score 7):

For `AppCompat` the changes to 2 styles are needed:

1)

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.CustomShareIcon</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.CustomShareIcon</item>
</style>
```

In other words, specifiing `attr:actionModeShareDrawable` in your `MyAppTheme` is not what you really need, but it should be mentioned in your `attr:actionBarWidgetTheme` as following:

2)

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.CustomShareIcon" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item> <!-- your icon goes here -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: Forget about the TRICKY way below, just sub-class ShareActionProvider, return null in `onCreateActionView` Method, and provide your own icon in menu.xml file, everything will be fine

===========================

I found a very tricky but none-ActionBarSherlock-specific way:

1. Sub-class ShareActionProvider, with just a little tweak:

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateActionView() {
       View target = super.onCreateActionView();
       ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.actionbutton_share, null);
       ImageView overlay = (ImageView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.overlay);
       ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.container);
       container.addView(target);
       container.getLayoutParams().width = overlay.getLayoutParams().width;
       container.getLayoutParams().height = overlay.getLayoutParams().height;
       return viewGroup;
   }
   ```
2. Create a layout file (R.layout.actionbutton_share), which place the original view at top but transparent to user (Note the "android:alpha=0" part) :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/container"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:alpha="0" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/overlay"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
           android:src="@drawable/yours_whatever_share_icon"
           tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
3. Use the hacked ShareActionProvider in your menu.xml file

Comment: Super . The override and return Null worked beautifully

Comment: The inherit, return null idea should be made its own answer. It worked for me. The way this answer is written is confusing at first.

Answer (score 3):

**vivimice**'s solution is good, but the icon of last used app for sharing becomes hidden too.

I did custom share icon as a common menu item without any ShareActionProvider, just in onOptionsItemSelected() method used this code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

It creates not a popup menu, but a chooser dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the non-public attribute like this.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="*android:actionModeShareDrawalbe">@drawable/icon</item>
</style>
```

(*) means reference to the non-public resources in Android

Comment: This option causes crashes on various devices. It is highly discouraged to use non-public Android attributes.

Comment: So is there a solution for non Sherlock themes? I am using custom theme that extends Holo.Light. Thing is, my share action icon needs to be white instead of dark gray icon of Holo.Light.

I have tried overriding non-public attribute as shown, but my device crash on start .no need to test further :). So ..any other solution?